# How to test api call using jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to test this react component with an API call using jest and react testing library

```
callApi = () => {
    fetch(this.getUrl())
    .then((result) => result.json())
        .then((jsonResult) => {
            this.setState({
                name: jsonResult.city.name,})
            for (var i = 0; i<jsonResult.list.length; i ++) {
                this.setState({
                    weather: [...this.state.weather, jsonResult.list[i].weather],
                    date: [...this.state.date, jsonResult.list[i].dt_txt],
                    clouds: [...this.state.clouds, jsonResult.list[i].clouds],
                    main: [...this.state.main, jsonResult.list[i].main],
                    wind: [...this.state.wind, jsonResult.list[i].wind],
                    rain: [...this.state.rain, jsonResult.list[i].rain],
                    snow: [...this.state.rain, jsonResult.list[i].rain]
            })}
            this.setState({
                list: jsonResult.list,
                name: jsonResult.city.name,})}
    )
}
```